# Having issue redirecting after user sign in using devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication

I am having issues trying to redirect a user to a user show page after they successfully sign in using devise for rails.  So far I have tried the following suggestions:
Changed devise_for to route to users show this way:

```
devise_for :user do
  root :to => "users#show"
end
```

Changed devise_for to route to users show this way:

```
devise_for :users do
    get 'users', :to => 'users#show', :as => :user_root
end
```

Even tried rerouting using:

```
match '/user' => "users#show", :as => :user_root
```

I also overwrote the registrations controller.

The error message I get after successful sign in is:
    Couldn't find User without an ID.

My users controller is set up as follows:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

end
```

Am I just missing something here?  Any help would greatly be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Figured it out.  I needed to overwrite the devise code for after_sign_in_path in the applications controller.  I did this with:

    protected
      def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
        user_path(resource)
    end

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out.  I needed to overwrite the devise code for after_sign_in_path in the applications controller.  I did this with:

```
protected
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    user_path(resource)
end
```

end